# pytest - unrecognized argument on cli invocation, despite being defined

Tags: python, linux, pytest

*This works on Windows without problems, but crashes on Linux.*

```
python setup.py test --addopts '--config myconf.ini'
```

---

I have defined a custom argument for testing to provide a test user credentials via a config file:

**`tests/conftest.py`:**

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--config', default='conf.ini', help='Path to the testing config file.')


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def configfile(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--config")
```

This is how I use it in testing files:

```
def test_foo(configfile):
    print(configfile)
```

---

On Windows, this works fine. On Linux, however, I get this (setup.cfg is configured to invoke pytest, so this is pytest's err output)

```
usage: setup.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
setup.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --config
  inifile: None
  rootdir: /uupmaker
```

What is interesting though, if I pass a filename to `--config fn` that *does not exist*, no error is thrown and the tests run normally (albeit as if there was no config file defined).

Have I overlooked something? Why won't this work?

---

Edit: `pip freeze --all` output:

```
certifi==2017.7.27.1
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.9
coverage==4.4.1
defusedxml==0.5.0
idna==2.6
jenkinsapi==0.3.4
jira==1.0.10
lxml==3.8.0
oauthlib==2.0.3
pbr==3.1.1
pip==9.0.1
py==1.4.34
pytest==3.2.2
pytest-runner==2.12.1
python-dateutil==2.6.1
pytz==2017.2
reaver==0.1.5
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
setuptools==28.8.0
six==1.10.0
teamcity-messages==1.21
urllib3==1.22
```

Using `Python 3.6.1`

`setup.cfg`:

```
[aliases]
test=pytest
```

---

This is the minimal working example for me: https://github.com/melkamar/pytest-setuppy-err

Simply clone that folder and run `python3 setup.py test --addopts "-s --config foo.bar"` and it *should* fail on Linux.

Comment: Which versions of setuptools, pytest-runner do you use? Can you attach the output of ` pip freeze --all`? I've just tried to reproduce the issue (on MacOSX with python 3.6.1 from pyenv), and it works totally fine.

Comment: Also, clarify "setup.cfg is configured to invoke pytest" sentence, please. Why is it setup.cfg, not setup.py? Do you use pytest-runner or some other technique to run the tests on `python setup.py test`? How exactly is your project configured?

Comment: setup.cfg contains this: `[aliases] test=pytest`. I will attach the versions when I am at work on Tuesday. I use python 3.6.1 though.

Comment: Added requested info as an edit of the question

Comment: Also added a minimal-working-example github repo

Comment: In my case, this works fine in local but fails with the below error while running in docker
`ERROR: pytest: error: unrecognized arguments:`
@MartinMelka Did you managed to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't think I did. It was for a smallish tool in my previous job and I think I just worked around it. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

So OP no longer needs it, but I had this exact issue and was sad to see it was not resolved.

Instead of using:

```
--config configfile
```

try with:

```
--config=configfile
```

That fixed it for me.